MS SQL Server plots points incorrectly in QGIS
I am using QGIS 3.43.3 - Prizren.

I have set up an MS SQL server link to a database and the data is coming in great but it looks to be plotting just a few metres off in the northing and the easting. I have brought the same data in as CSV which does plot correctly.
When I query both sets of points the CSV is plotting where the northing and easting says it should but the MS SQL Server is plotting differently from what it states the actual data is in the database. Both have the same CRS information in the properties tabs.
I have a few screenshots but can't figure out how to post them here - rookie alert.


in edit mode use the mountain icon to upload screenshots. like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Hi and welcome to GIS.SE!
When you query your data directly in SQL Server, select <geomColumn>.STX, <geomColumn>.STY from <table>, does it show the correct coordinates?
What is the CRS of the QGIS project, what is the CRS of the SQL Server data?

Please [Edit] the Question to specify the version of SQL Server. Last I heard, Microsoft used an integer compression algorithm similar to Esri's, but with smaller integers, so rougher coordinate space. Setting a false origin of  {100000,500000} would likely yield an extra digit, but using a modern release would increase precision., too

Thanks Vince. The version is in there QGIS 3.43.3 - Prizren
